# Is the LSTM share the same model parameter in each block?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, rnn

I learn the LSTM recently, and a little bit confuse about the model parameters about LSTM,

The follow is the [LSTM structure](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)

[image]

And it is equation as (I slightly ignore the bias in each equation):

$$i_t = \sigma(x_tU^i + h_{t-1}W^i)$$
$$f_t = \sigma(x_tU^f + h_{t-1}W^f)$$
$$o_t = \sigma(x_tU^o + h_{t-1}W^o)$$
$$\tilde{C}_t = \tanh(x_tU^g + h_{t-1}W^g)$$
$$C_t=\sigma(f_t*C_{t-1} + i_{t}*\tilde{C}_t)$$
$$h_t = \tanh(C_t)*o_t$$

I am confused about the parameters: $U^i, U^f, U^o , U^g$ and $W^i, W^f, W^o , W^g$.  Are those parameters trained by data(e.g., back-propagation)?

My second question is that, In the Figure, We have the three block of LSTM `1`, `2`, and `3` (mark by blue color). Do them share the same $U^i, U^f, U^o , U^g$ and $W^i, W^f, W^o , W^g$. ?  Or each block have their own $U^*$ and $W^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused about the parameters: $U^i, U^f, U^o , U^g$ and $W^i, W^f, W^o , W^g$.  Are those parameters trained by data(e.g., back-propagation)?

Yes. They do get trained by backpropagation. There are caveats here. Variants to backprop too exist when training a sequence-to-sequence to models. Check out [BPTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time) for example.

> My second question is that, In the Figure, We have the three block of LSTM `1`, `2`, and `3` (mark by blue color). Do them share the same $U^i, U^f, U^o , U^g$ and $W^i, W^f, W^o , W^g$. ?  Or each block have their own $U^*$ and $W^*$?

Each block has the same set of weights shared among them.

An following mini example demo would be like in Keras.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(None, 100)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

creates an simple `LSTM` model. If you look at model summary to count the params you got.

```
model.summary
```

You will get

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 128)               117248    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 117,377
Trainable params: 117,377
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And the total of `117,377` params you see is obtained from `(((128*128)+(128*100)) * 4) + (4*128)`. Here **W** is of size `128*100` and **U** is `128*128` and there are `4` of them resp. and last `4*128` goes for the biases.

Comment: Thanks. Correct me if I am wrong, (1) In the forward, $W$ and $U$ are the same for cell `1`,`2` and `3`.  (2) in the  "Backpropagation through time", I don't quite understand. Does $W$ and $U$ update for all three cell at the same time? Or we first update $W, U$ in cell `3`, then, update $W, U$ in cell `2`, then in cell `1`. If we do this, the next forward, the $W, U$  now have different value for cell `1`,`2` and `3`.